# Почему скомпилированный vue js не работает когда находится в body?

Tags: vue.js

Помогите понять  почему скомпилированный vue js файл  работает только в HTML Head элементе  а  cdn vue js работает и в ***HTML Head*** элементе и в ***HTML  Body*** элементе ?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: По вашему вопросу понял , что так не должно быть и код должен работать и в HEAD и в  BODY , если не правильно понял пожалуйста поправьте меня.

Comment: Скрипт должен загружаться и выполнятся независимо от того в head или в body.

Comment: И что значит `скомпилированный vue js файл`?

Comment: Речь идет о файле который  получается после использования webpack  (app.js  или bundle.js)  ,  конечно это не компилятор  как скажем  в (c++, java)  но в частности Laravel mix  после завершении работы отправляет сообщение (files compiled)  вот почему в вопросе использую  это слово. Если можно было бы сформулировать вопрос более правильно прощу поправить меня.

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы взглянуть на код, а так могу предположить что ссылка на vue js не корректная, или же можете попробовать прописать defer в тэге script

```
<script src="<ссылка на фреймворк>" defer></script>
```